# Javascript Unicode Conversion and Search

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, escaping, character-codes

I'm wondering whether anyone has any insight on converting an array of character codes to Unicode characters, and searching them with a regex.

If you have

```
var a = [0,1,2,3]
```

you can use a loop to convert them into a string of the first four control characters in unicode.

However, if you then want to create a regex

```
"(X)+"
```

where X == the character code 3 converted to its Unicode equivalent, the searches never seem to work. If I check for the length of the string, it's correct, and .* returns all the characters in the string. But I'm having difficulties constructing a regex to search the string, when all I have to begin with is the character codes. Any advise?

Edit:

var a = [0,1,2,3,0x111];
    str = "";

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(a[i]);
}

var r = [0x111]
var reg = ""

reg += "(";
for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
var hex = r[i].toString(16);
    reg += "\\x" + hex;
}
reg += ")";

var res = str.match(RegExp(reg))[0];
```

Edit

```
//Working code:
var a = [0,1,2,3,0x111];
str = "";

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(a[i]);
}

var r = [3,0x111]
var reg = ""

reg += "(";
for(var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    var hex = r[i].toString(16);
    reg += ((hex.length > 2) ? "\\u" : "\\x") + ("0000" + hex).slice((hex.length > 2) ? -4 : -2);
}
reg += ")";

var res = str.match(RegExp(reg))[0];
```

Comment: Can you post just a few line code example of exactly what you are trying to do -- a minimal example that we can look at, rather than guess at?  In its current form, it is very difficult to answer this question.

Comment: I hope the above edit is sufficient to get the basic idea across, though in the actual application it will be significantly more sophisticated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With changes to a few details, the example can be made to work.

Assuming that you are interested in printable Unicode characters in general, and not specifically the first four control characters, the test vector `a` for the string "hello" would be:

```
var a = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]; // hello
```

If you want to match both 'l' characters:

```
var r = [108, 108]
```

When you construct your regular expression, the character code must be in hexadecimal:

```
reg += "\\x" + ("0" + r[i].toString(16)).slice(-2);
```

After that, you should see the results you expect.

Comment: Right, so when I stringify the regex with either method, I get (\x2\x3). That tests negative against a string containing the first four unicode characters, while (.)* tests positive for the whole string.

Comment: Hardcoding (\x02\x03) tests positive, so I guess a single character hex doesn't cut it. Any thoughts on formatting hex strings like this?

Comment: Edited to perform padding with leading zero.  If using `\uxxxx` in your regular expression (where `xxxx` is four hexadecimal digits for the Unicode character), the leading pad string would have three zeroes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You're padding solution is genious.

Comment: So, I generate a regex like (\x000002\x000003) and compare it against the string containing the first four unicode characters in order. It returns negative even though (\x02\x03) returns positive. Any idea why?

Comment: Use `\xhh` when you have two hex digits and `\uhhhh when you have four hexadecimal digits.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Comment: I posted the working code as an edit. Thanks for all your help!